# Embed plotly interactive graphs in markdown file (index.md) with GitHub pages, not using Jekyll

Tags: python, plotly, markdown

I have some interactive graphs made with plotly and would like to embed them on my "webpage" that I created using GitHub pages. I tried something like {%include myfig.html%} but it tells me that the file is not found in the _include file. However, I cannot take hands on this file...

Any simple way to embed a plotly interactive graph on markdown using github pages ? I've looked for it on the net but could not find anything that helps me.

Comment: You might try hosting `myfig.html` on GitHub and showing it using `<iframe>` tag. You can normally use html tags in Markdown, however, [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-653) might not allow you to use `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was actually quite simple : Just use the commande: {% include_relative myfile.html} instead of {% include myfile.html %}